# Get Session From /app/Config/email.php

Tags: session, cakephp-2.0

I want to send an email using CakeEmail, but I need to take from Session the user email and the password from email.php. How can I do this?

email.php:

```
public $smtp = array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'from' => array($_SESSION['UserLogged']['User']['email'] => $_SESSION['UserLogged']['User']['name']),
            'username' => $_SESSION['UserLogged']['User']['email'],
            'password' => $_SESSION['UserLogged']['User']['password'],
            'transport' => 'Smtp',
            'tls' => false // As of 2.3.0 you can also enable TLS SMTP
    );
```

I can't take this values from Session because it can't be read in email.php and I can't set password from controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve..
In my Controller:

```
$email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
                $email->config(array(
                        // 'port' => 465,
                        'from' => array($this->Session->read('UserLogged')['User']['email'] => $this->Session->read('UserLogged')['User']['name']),
                        'username' => $this->Session->read('UserLogged')['User']['email'],
                        'password' => $this->Session->read('UserLogged')['User']['password']
                ));
                $email->to($this->request->data['BlogPosts']['to']);
                $email->subject($this->request->data['BlogPosts']['subject']);
                $email->send($this->request->data['BlogPosts']['message']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain much around what is happening before and what happens after. I make a guess, a user is added, changed or sending new generated password.

You should look into CakeMail: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html.

This example might help:

```
<?php
    //UsersController.php    

        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            $pwBeforeHash = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
            // Uncomment the line below if its a new inserted row in table
            //$this->User->create();
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){

                $Email = new CakeEmail();
                $Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'));
                $Email->to('you@example.com');
                $Email->subject('New password');
                $Email->send('Hi. This is your new password: ' . $pwBeforeHash);

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password is sent to your email'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Due to an unknown error, the new password could not be sent. Try again.'));
            }
        }
        ?>
```

If you really need to get value from session you should read this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html.

Password should not be saved in a session.

If you need to read a session, use: `$stringToMySession = $this->Session->read('mySession');`

Comment: Yes, the solution is bellow, Thank you